# How to bind UITextField clear button with RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, rx-swift, uitextfielddelegate

I need to handle UITextField statuses.

So I bind my emailTextField with this way

```
Observable.combineLatest(
            emailTxf.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidBegin),
            emailTxf.rx.controlEvent(.editingChanged),
            emailTxf.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidEnd))
            .asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
                // DoSomething()
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This code can't cover the clear button on UITextField. 
So If I press the **clear button** after writing something on UITextField, It doesn't detect the textField status.

I know there is **allEditingEvents** control event. 
But not sure it's okay to use **allEditingEvents** for detecting **clear button** 
Is this okay to use **allEditingEvents**? or is there better way to handle it?

Comment: its fine for detect the change, if you want to obeserve the clear button action you need to handle the textfield delegate method of  textFieldShouldClear.

Answer (score 2):

You can observe `emailTxf.rx.text` directly and check if the text is empty. This should cover the case for **clear button**